# How to force a Chrome extension to load after inline install

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a website which includes an inline installation of Chrome extension.

The problem is that once the extension is installed it doesn't act on the my website until the user refresh the page. Is there a way to load the extension on the existing page without refresh?

Comment: Do you have content scripts in your extension??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can not load you extension without reload exsiting page after install.

so I think, try to use `chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)`

and call `location.reload()` in suncessCallback function.